# Apache2: Illegal attempt to re-initialise SSL for server

Tags: php, apache

For some reason I get this error (it was working on another machine).

This is the error I get from the Apache log: Illegal attempt to re-initialise SSL for server (SSLEngine On should go in the VirtualHost, not in global scope.) This is an Apache / PHP-FPM config

This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/public_html
    
    <Directory /home/public_html>
        AllowOverride all
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup xxx xxx
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://xxx.xxx.xxx/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
    DocumentRoot /home/public_html
    
    <Directory /home/public_html>
        AllowOverride all
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxx.xxx/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxx.xxx/privkey.pem
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup xxx xxx
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://xxx.xxx.xxx/$1 [R,L]
    
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        #Run php-fpm via proxy_fcgi
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/xxx.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have 2 vhosts for the same site on port 80/443

How to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have another "SSLEngine On" somewhere in the apache config files.